# Swift 3 ternary operator Error Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a function

```
func test (food_item_raw:NSArray){

    for j in 0...food_item_raw.count-1{

        let food_name = food_item_raw[j]["food_name"] as? String == nil ? "nil" : food_item_raw[j]["food_name"] as! String

        let food_url = food_item_raw[j]["food_url"] as? String == nil ? "nil" : food_item_raw[j]["food_url"] as! String

        let food_price = food_item_raw[j]["food_price"] as? String == nil ? "nil" : food_item_raw[j]["food_price"] as! String

        let food_desc = food_item_raw[j]["food_desc"] as? String == nil ? "nil" : food_item_raw[j]["food_desc"] as! String

        //let food_item = FoodItems(food_url: food_url, food_name: food_name, food_catagory: food_type,food_price: food_price, food_desc: food_desc)

        //weakFoodArray.append(food_item)

    }
}
```

this was working fine in swift 2 and swift 2.3 but in swift 3 I am getting error `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`

here is screenshot

[image: code screen shot]

Comment: I don't think it's a Ternary operator issue. I guess that if you write `prinf(food_item_raw[j]["food_name"])` you'll get the same issue. I'd say that you may have to (and it may be clearer): `let foodObject = food_item_raw[j] as NSDictionary` (or assimilated like `[String:Any]`), then `let food_name = foodObject["food_name"] as? String == nil ? "nil" : foodObject["food_name"] as! String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it happens?**

`NSArray` in Swift 3 is bridged to `[Any]`.
 So `food_item_raw[j]` has type `Any`.

And here's your `Error Type 'Any' has no subscript members`.
`Any` is empty protocol, it has nothing, not even `subscript`.

**Solution**

To prevent this just add some types, change `NSArray` to `[T]`, where `T` is the Type, it your case it looks like `T == [String: String]`. 
It will save you from type casting in every line too.

You can change your code to this, for example:

```
func test (food_item_raw:[[String: String]]) {

    for food_item in food_item_raw {

        let food_name = food_item["food_name"] ?? "nil"

        let food_url = food_item["food_url"] ?? "nil"

        let food_price = food_item["food_price"] ?? "nil"

        let food_desc = food_item["food_desc"] ?? "nil"

        //let food_item = FoodItems(food_url: food_url, food_name: food_name, food_catagory: food_type,food_price: food_price, food_desc: food_desc)

        //weakFoodArray.append(food_item)

    }
}
```

And, btw, i replaced for by index with enumerating for, because `food_item_raw[j]` in every line is redundant and looks silly.

Also that huge overcomplicated ternary operator can be replaced with [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)(`??`), which does same thing, but is way shorter.

Comment: so basically NSArray is equivalent to [[String: String]] ? isn't

Comment: In your case, in that function yes, it is. Or, to be more correct: in your case you *should* use `[[String: String]]` instead of `NSArray`.

Comment: ok, one more question if food_item["food_name"] returns nil then what ? does this food_name = "nil" (nil as string)

Comment: `??` operator? If left operand of this operator is nil, `??` returns right operand, otherwise it returns unwrapped left operand. `nil ?? value == value`.  Or in `food_item["food_name"] ?? "nil"`, if there's value for `food_item["food_name"]`it will be set in variable `food_name`, otherwise `food_name` variable would be initialized with right operand value of `??`, `"nil"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your use of the Objective-C type NSArray (in the very first line). You need to cast this thing to a Swift array of whatever element type it really contains. It looks like its type is `[[String:Any]]`, perhaps. Or maybe `[[String:String]]`.

What you are doing was always a bad idea, and now Swift 3 is telling you so. This is Swift. Use Swift types.